# List not callable in Python Tkinter Tic Tac Toe using lambda

Tags: python, tkinter, tic-tac-toe

In my code I am required to use Lambda to create the button board however I am having errors trying to call the buttons. I have tried switching the () to [] as I saw suggested in another forum however I have not been able to make it work.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

myFont = font.Font(family = "Courier", size = 80)

who = True
turn = 0

#changing turns and choosing tiles
def update(x,y):
    global who, turn
    if board(x,y)["text"] == "-" and who == True:#<-----------Error
        board(x,y)["text"] = "X"
        who = False
        turn += 1
    elif board(x,y)["text"] == "-" and who == False:
        board(x,y)["text"] = "0"
        who = True
        turn += 1
    else:
        print("That Box has already been chosen")
    
    
    
board = [[Button(root, text = "-", font = myFont, command = (lambda x = x, y = y: update(x,y))) for y in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
#^^^^^ The cause of my frustration

for x in range(3):
    for y in range(3):
        board[x][y].grid(row=x,column=y)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Okay, so. At the bottom of your code, you have: `board[x][y].grid(row=x,column=y)`. Did that work as you expect for accessing the individual `Button`s in `board`? Yes? Well then, in the current code, where you again want to access one of the individual `Button`s in `board`, *why not try doing it the same way*? Then, once you have the `Button`, *what does the documentation say* about how to access the button's text?

Comment: I recommend you use a beginner's forumn like learnpython.reddit.com for beginner level questions like these.

Comment: Just wanted to add a comment. Never check Boolean values with true or false. For example, instead of writing if who == True, you should simply write if who. For more information on this, check out https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#introduction

Comment: That part you are referencing is part of the starter code i was given and haphazardly overlooked. Thank you, It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
if board[x][y]["text"] == "-"
```

Just like in the grid loop.